# Shockwave througth http proxy on windows

Tags: windows-7, proxy, flash

Is it possible? I have an http proxy which requires authentication, while browsers go fine Shockwave apps don't respond, I guess because they open a new connection.

Answer (score 1):

if the shockwave app in general opens the http connection through the proxy and just the authentication fails, you may want to try [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/).

If the app is not using proxy, you may whish to use a [transparent proxy](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/cntlm.1.html) and forward all [outoing traffic to port 80 to the port of the proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/101234/redirecting-port-80-to-another-port-on-a-single-windows-computer).

Comment: Problem is that shockwave in linux is only available with wine, and I don't want that...for this reason I'm using windows 7, isn't there an equivalent solution to cntlm?

Comment: cntlm is running with windows: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/files/cntlm/cntlm%200.92.3/cntlm-0.92.3-setup.exe/download

Comment: it doesn't appear to work...browser's connection is redirected but shockwave is not! From sniffing it appears that no connection is estabilished at all

Comment: that's somewhat strange that the adobe plugins don't seem to honour the proxy settings, this is why outgoing traffic must be redirected on tcp level. Did you try reroute outgoing TCP/80 to the ctnlm listening port?

Comment: yes I did..no result :(